# Background-image won't show up in any other browsers

Tags: html, css, background-image

Decided to place an image as background and it looks fine in my browser but doesn't anywhere else. Haven't found any answers yet. HELP.

```
<style> html{
background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T6Nt.jpg);
background-color:rgb(105,95,42);} </style>
```

I set a color as backup.

The webpage: https://codepen.io/Miosad/full/XzRPXR

EDIT: I tried the code with another image and that seems to be the problem. Any idea why this would be? The image url is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T6Nt.jpg

EDIT 2: Found out it was the image. Thanks for all the help and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: "*it looks fine in my browser but doesn't anywhere else*". Where other than a browser are you loading the page? What about loading it in those other locations makes it look bad?

Comment: You probably want it on the body?

Comment: I've looked at it with IE and in my phone with Safari and Chrome. Doesn't show up in any of those.

Comment: Tried it on the body and it doesn't work either. It might be the image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the background to `body` rather than `html`:

```
body{
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/02nQ1hD.jpg);
  background-color:rgb(105,95,42);
  color:rgb(0,0,0);
  font-family:garamond, bookman, palatino, georgia;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

I've created an updated CodePen showcasing this **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/MOvEdG)**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured it out, the problem was the image.